# Symfony internalization routes with params

Tags: symfony, url, translation, placeholder

I am developing a project in Symfony 4.3. I am trying to create URLs in different languages. I have tried to use this notation:

```
/**
 * @Route({
 *     "it": "/{_locale}/rassegna/stampa",
 *     "bg": "/{_locale}/Статии/в/печата"
 * }, name="rassegna_stampa", utf8=true)
 */
```

The problem is that when I try to create a link in a twig to change language, for example:

```
<a href="{{path('rassegna_stampa', {'_locale':'bg'})}}">GO TO BG LANGUAGE</a>
```

it is rendered in something like:

```
http://website.it/it/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8/%D0%B2/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0
```

So it seems that the translated final part is ok, but the _locale parameter is not matched, as the {_locale} placeholder is filled with the current locale, and not with the locale that I requested in the link. It is 'it' but it should be 'bg'.